# Scrolling in Webkit / mozilla while overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css, webkit, overflow, opera

Is there a way to tell Safari / Webkit browsers and Firefox to scroll an element or a page while overflow is set to "hidden"?

I'm using `overflow: hidden` on the body-Element and it works for Opera only.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show your code for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is one of those cases where Opera does it differently from everyone else. Overflow is supposed to prevent scrolling if its value is hidden, not just hide scroll bars.

If you really want to hide the scroll bars, but still want to scroll the window or its contents, you can use JavaScript / DOM script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you have been mistaken, the overflow-x:hidden or overflow-y:hidden must be applied to the html element, not body element. But in just the case I have googled it and found these
link tell me if they did any help.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3560359.htm

http://www.artmov.com/dev/snippets/apply-overflow-x-overflow-y-to-body-in-ie7-ie6-84/
(In this link I found the above mentioned statement.)

http://haslayout.net/css/Document-Scrollbars-Overflow-Inconsistency

In this link I found that you should apply directly overflow value in the `<HTML>` tag.

Hope it works!

Comment: Tested several things, but no chance. Does not work with overflow: hidden on html or body or any other element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting `overflow: hidden` on any element, you're explicitly telling it that the contents should be hidden, and therefore can't be scrolled to. If you want the contents to be scrollable, then you need to use `overflow: auto`. Why would you ever want to scroll something you're telling the browser it should not scroll? It's contradictory.

Comment: But `overflow: auto` will show show the scrollbars. I don't want scrollbars but the functionality to scroll.

Comment: How will people scroll without having any scrollbars?

Comment: @PhilPowell, people using trackpads, can still do 2-finger scrolling within those elements.